# Is there any code for saving characters automatically which are pressed by user to database -without send button-

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, database

It can be JavaScript, Ajax or PHP. A need a real code parts or good guide. Is there any link?

Purpose of this: I am planning a keyboard game which is running with characters which are pressed by user. If user press the button a, I have to sent send this data to MySQL database. Is this possible? If yes, with which code?

Comment: Do you know how to capture keypresses? Do you know how to make an Ajax call? Do you know how to handle a post request in PHP? Do you know how to write to a database in PHP? Do each part and it will work.

Comment: I can only strongly advise against this endeavor. Games typically need a tremendously optimized networking to work fluently. If this is anything other than a POC or just for educational purposes: DON'T DO THIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using jQuery framework you can use [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event (if you're not using jQuery you can still use a [keypress events](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp) but jQuery makes it easier!)

From the docs:

```
$("#target").keypress(function(event) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
     event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

`e.which` will give you access to the keycode the user pressed.  With this you can easily respond to specific key presses.  13 is a javascript [keyboard code](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) for 'enter'  So perhaps you want to save all input to a variable that user types on the keyboard and when enter is typed you can send that data using ajax. jQuery makes this very simple.

Comment: Upvoted as it seems to be the key nonconventional component that the OP is missing.